# delete the contents of an edittext

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I have 9 edittext and a button back I look when we click on the button back the content of a selected edittext is delete help me please

```
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        et1.addTextChangedListener(this);

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (count == 0) {
                //text was deleted.
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You could try and use et1.setText("");

Comment: Another possibility - editText.getText().clear();

Answer (score 0):

```
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(et1.getText().toString()) {
        //your first edit text is empty
    }
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to the code so that the OP can understand how it may help him.

Comment: 9 editext how to delete the contents of an edittext selected pa example {editext1, edittext2, .... edittxt9} the 9 editext have values {editext1 = 1, edittext2 = 2, editext3 = 3, editetx4= 4,...edittext9= 9} how can I override them values of a selected edittext and the others remains ?? when we click on a button that is to say delete the values of a selected edittext. thank you very much